# How to integrate 'windows.github.com' with Visual Studio 2010 OR Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, github-for-windows

I have recently found haacked article about [Github For Windows](http://haacked.com/archive/2012/05/21/introducing-github-for-windows.aspx). But in this article he is not mentioned how to use/integrate it with VS 2010 or 2012. Anyone is able to do this?

Answer (score 3):

in MSVC 2010

(tools)(extension manager)(online gallery)

search for git

pick the git source control provider and install it.

restart msvc and you are good to go.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the GitHub for Windows product

Comment: Actually, it does in a round about way.  By installing this extension you will get Visual Studio integration with your GitHub for Windows project.  Although this extension requires the install of a separate version of Git, Git all works the same.  You will be able to see what files are modified in Solution Explorer, undo changes, etc.  These will also show up in GH4W too.

One important note; in VS2012 in order to get this to work you need to go in to VS2012 settings and explicitly choose Git as your source control provider.